# What was the purpose of the "monster" programs in the Nightmare Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

I'm curious about what the exact role of the "monster" programs (like some of the exiles we see in the films; the Ghost Twins, vampires, etc) was in the [Nightmare Matrix](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Nightmare_Matrix) (so before they were exiles).

Taken from the Matrix wiki page about "[Monsters](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Monsters)":

> Based on the comments and behaviors of the Architect, Persephone, and the Merovingian, it is strongly suggested that the Architect used virtual monsters **to frighten the inhabitants of the earlier versions of the Matrix.**

So, according to that, they were there to primarily scare the bluepills of the Nightmare Matrix. This matches up with what we understand the Nightmare Matrix to be:

> Architect: The first Matrix I designed was quite naturally perfect ... The inevitability of its doom is apparent to me now as a consequence of the imperfection inherent in every human being. **Thus, I redesigned it based on your history to more accurately reflect the varying grotesqueries of your nature.** However, I was again frustrated by failure.
>
> <sup>*[The Matrix Reloaded transcript](https://www.matrixfans.net/movies/the-matrix-reloaded/transcript/)*</sup>

I've seen some answers on this site suggest that the "monsters" programs served a similar function to Agents; as a recent example, taken from [this answer](https://www.matrixfans.net/movies/the-matrix-reloaded/transcript/):

> Also, **they may also have been used as the Nightmare Matrix's equivalent of Agents** since Agents are also very powerful, similar to how the Seraphim are angelic Exile programs which acted like Agents in the Paradise Matrix (the first Matrix beta).

However, there are aspects of this that don't make much sense to me; if they were just there to scare the bluepills, how does that make them function like Agents? The Seraphim I have an easier time understanding how their role more so resembles that of an Agent from the current Matrix, but the "monsters" don't seem to fit that description as well.

What's more, it seems to me like they also enjoy not only *scaring* people, but also *killing* people. During the freeway chase scene in *The Matrix: Reloaded*, there's a point where a vehicle is between the Ghost Twins and the heroes, blocking the Twins gunfire.

The moment that stands out to me is when the Twin with the gun smiles evily before gunning down the driver so that the vehicle cannot keep up with the other two vehicles (the Twins' and the heroes'). This "evil smile", to me, implies that it was more than a simple "get out of the way!", but rather, he enjoyed the opportunity/excuse to kill someone.

So "monster" programs that enjoy not only scaring but also killing would seem to make poor "Agents", and even without the comparison to Agents, they would surely unnecessarily destroy a lot of the machines' "crop", thus threatening the whole point of the Matrix; to syphon power from humans (humans as batteries, etc).

This is presumably what is meant by this quote:

> Persephone: They come from a much older version of the Matrix, but **like so many back then, they caused more problems than they solved.**
>
> <sup>*[The Matrix Reloaded transcript](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/236296/85712)*</sup>

So, what was the exact role of the "monster" programs, and how does that make any sense? How does scaring and killing people somehow help the Nightmare Matrix, and how does this compare to an Agent's role in the current Matrix? Or have I missed the point of what the role of the "monster" programs was in the Nightmare Matrix?

Comment: Scaring people stops them noticing that they're in a simulation. Presumably the monsters would kill any redpills who're causing problems.

Comment: I just assumed they were earlier versions of agents that were retained, not created as "monster" programs. But as time goes, on, you refine things, and find better, more efficient ways to do things.

Comment: Not every program is necessarily an equivalent to the Agents. For a horror show you need monsters, so presumably some programs were specifically designed for that function: not as Agents, but the equivalent of NPC minions. Lord Darkcape the Master Vampire might have been the equivalent of an Agent, keeping the human meatsacks in line but simultaneously not allowing them to be totally defeated (as that would defeat the purpose of the Matrix itself), but lesser programs would be the average vampires and werewolves. These programs would have no purpose in a "mundane" Matrix and thus be exiles.

Comment: @DKN No, the "monsters" were pretty clearly designed as monsters; the Agents didn't exist back then and would have been created as-is for the current Matrix. The "monsters" were not refined into Agents, they are separate

Comment: @Keith I do not dispute that the "monsters" serve no purpose now and thus are exiles; this question is purely just about clarifying their purpose back in the older version of the Matrix, the Nightmare Matrix. Understanding exactly how Lord Darkcape could be thought of as an equivalent of an Agent is what I'm after. I think something between yours and Valorum's comments could be the start of a good answer, though...

Comment: @NathanS How can you say they are not refined or revised versions? They both play the same role at times in the movies. And it doesn't matter if nothing labelled "agents" didn't exist back then. That logic is like saying weapons didn't exist in the bronze age because guns didn't exist back then. It's possible to use different methods to achieve the same ends.

Comment: @DKN We may be speaking at cross purposes; I'm saying that the Agent programs we see in the modern Matrix were not written until they wrote the modern Matrix; they would not have existed during the Nightmare Matrix. The monster programs were written back as monsters then but became obsolete, thus becoming exiles (because they didn't want to be deleted), but they were not "re-written" or otherwise repurposed. Is that not what you were saying? Have I misunderstood?

Comment: @NathanS You have not misunderstood. Obviously they are not repurposed. But I don't see how you could think they have definitively not been re-written (or more likely, past experience caused future versions to be written with a different approach). They're both still enforcement software.

Comment: @DKN Ah, by rewritten, do you mean future Agents being written based on how the Monster programs turned out, rather than, say, writing the Agents from scratch blindly? I assumed before that you meant the monster programs were themselves being overwritten somehow... but that's probably not what you were saying at all.

Comment: @NathanS Well, if you rewrite things enough times they can end up being very different. But you can also just rebuild things from scratch using experience from past "field results". My point was that they could seem so very different because a different approach was taken to fulfill the same role after initial approaches didn't work so well, but that doesn't change their purpose.

Comment: @NathanSWell Agents wouldn't make much sense in a perfect "dream world" where you presumably did not need to work or have authoritative organizations . Ethereal horrors might fit in better to enforce things in that setting just popping in and out as needed. On the other hand, in a modern setting, you can't have so many ethereal horrors running around. Plus, masqueraded as authority you could get the jacked humans to assist you, though I suppose angels could do the same thing...but people might be skeptical if interaction is too high which it would have to be to do that.

Comment: They are systems of control. But let's not forget what the Oracle said, "Every time you’ve heard someone say they saw a ghost, or an angel. Every story you’ve ever heard about vampires, werewolves, or aliens is the system assimilating some program that’s doing something they’re not supposed to be doing."